# Programmatically Assign Attributes to Products in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I am performing a mass product import and have automation scripts to handle all aspects of imports besides attribute assignments. I've spent many hours looking for resources for a solution and can't seem to find one, even through programming my own. So far I am successfully altering the product object but it's not actually saving or retaining the changes. It seems I'm finding a lot of contradicting information out there on how to go about it as well. Has anyone successfully written a script to accomplish this?

```
// This is my latest attempt. All variables are populated ($attributeName for example)

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setCurrentStore(1)->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
$product->getResource()->addAttributeUpdate($attributeName, $value, 0);

$product->getResource()->addAttributeUpdate($attributeName, $value, 0);
$product->save();
```

I've also been trying the following, once having the product and attribute objects similar to how I instantiated them earlier:

```
$product->addAttributeUpdate($attributeName, $value, 0);

$product->setData('diameter', '10.5');
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'diameter', '2');
```

I'm really quite baffled at this point. Anyone with any suggestions? They'd be much appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yep, I feel downright ridiculous, but I feel the documentation could be clearer on this. I was saving the **value** of the attribute, not the corresponding _id_ of it. Once I returned the attribute ID it worked. Hopefully this helps someone someday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bulk import module to import bulk product.

[AvS Fast Simple Import](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/).

for this module you have to create multidimensional array.

**Note** : You dont have to put attribute option id in this array (Attribute value will work).